# Firebase hosting custom domain error

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

I have recently acquired a .tk domain and was willing to link it to Firebase hosting as a custom domain.

After reading documentation and following the tutorial, I successfully deployed my first app to Firebase hosting. It is accessible via the default firebaseapp.com url.

However, after trying to set up a custom domain, I have had problems trying to verify my ownership of the domain. I added two TXT DNS records as instructed and have waited for a day for Firebase to verify, but I get the following error:

> There was a problem connecting your custom domain. Please contact support.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: *Firebaser here* Did you already contact Firebase support? If not, please do so and tell them your project name (`https://console.firebase.google.com/project/<project-name>`). With that we'll be able to investigate. Hang in there, we're pushing them out as quickly as we can.

Comment: Thanks. It's now working, @FrankvanPuffelen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was a known problem and has been **RESOLVED** by the Firebase team.

> Michael Bleigh: We're working on a capacity issue with the domain provisioning system.

Tracked on the **[group discussion "Can't get custom domain to verify"](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/ko-G8ZRN3as)**

Answer (score 8):

I observed this error when migrating a domain between two Firebase projects quickly.

I resolved it by following these steps:

1. Remove all Firebase related DNS records from your DNS provider
2. Unlink your custom domain from your current project's hosting console
3. Start the linking process again.  The TXT records may have changed, so double check them before applying them to your DNS configuration
4. Wait 5-10 minutes and re-verify your custom domain with your Firebase project.
5. Verify that the TXT records are propagated -- You can check using `dig TXT example.com` on command line, or a web tool like [this one](https://toolbox.googleapps.com/apps/dig/#TXT).  The TXT records should look similar to this:

   ```
   ;QUESTION
   example.com. IN TXT
   ;ANSWER
   example.com. 299 IN TXT "firebase=examplefirebase"
   example.com. 299 IN TXT "globalsign-domain-verification=21qwertyjklRSFsjalkfe432dswlaGgi2Bafsad"
   ```

Answer (score 2):

I was having this problem while trying to add a custom domain i had through Namecheap. I had added custom domains successfully a few times, so I was pretty sure the problem was either on Namecheap or Firebase's side... about 30min after my initial several tries, I gave it another go.

I followed mimming's advice above.
But the first time it didn't work yet again.

I don't know if it's coincidence or what, but after checking the TXT via bash/terminal, Firebase was suddenly able to verify my domain. Maybe the 5-10 min delay mimming recommends kicked in right then. 
I know this isn't really a "solution", but I hope my experience can give some guidance.