# Firebase Hosting from freenom (dot.tk)

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

I would like to host my webapp on Firebase, since I'm using their services and functionalities since a long time (before Firebase was inside Google and since its static hosting service was named Divshot... ).

But I've got a demo domain from Freenom (.tk domain) and I was wondering how to connect this with firebase:

I can set only this paramater relative to TXT record:

[dns management](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GPhSn.png)

so where should I define the parameters needed

google-site-verification=...

?

Thank You to all!

PS: I've already seen

[Firebase hosting custom domain error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37353907/firebase-hosting-custom-domain-error)

and related

firebase-talk Dqmz9Iuio54

and

and the question: how-can-i-verify-my-custom-domain-using-domains-google-com/39020649#39020649

but none of them seems to respond to my problem...

PS: I've come here from firebase support page where StackOverflow is the first choice.

Thank you!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Leave the "Name" field blank and fill "Target" with the `google-site-verification=...` value. Once you've done so, things should go through. One way to check is to run:

```
dig yourdomain.tk TXT
```

If you've done it correctly, you should receive back the `google-site-verification=...` value. It may take some time to propagate before it starts showing up.

Comment: That works perfectly, but how can you redirect all the www.domain.ml to domain.ml ?

Comment: @Nico you need to add a custom domain first, then  add 2nd one with www as a redirect.

Answer (score 1):

1. DNS registrar / records host: delete TXT records pointing to
   firebase.
2. firebase console: delete the custom domain.
3. firebase console: add custom domain.
4. copy the two TXT records from firebase to DNS host
5. DNS record host should include two entries with one yourdomain.tk and [www.yourdomain.tk](http://www.yourdomain.tk)
6. Once the yourdomain.tk is added it'll  show as empty and other entry will be shown as www.
7. The copy the two given A records to Freenom DNS records.
8. There will be 4 A records two for yourdomain.tk and two for [www.yourdomain.tk](http://www.yourdomain.tk).
9. Wait 24-48 hours to see if the changes work.
10. If it doesn't work, contact firebase support from the console; be sure to take screen shots of the DNS records and the firebase console. These will help the firebase support team to troubleshoot the problem.
    Mean while you can check for the dns propagation by using below tutorial

The Firebase Hosting servers run what is essentially this command for verifying the TXT records for your domain:

```
dig -t txt +noall +answer yourdomain.tk
```

If you immediately run this command right now, you might not get results. If the Firebase servers are seeing the same in their DNS query, they will not be able to continue.

That means that either you didn't save/apply your changes yet, or they haven't propagated everywhere yet. The longer it takes for the changes to show up, the more likely it becomes that you still need to take some action at your DNS provider